# Rails with turbo stream do not find the view matching the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo

I am on rails 7 with turbo-rails installed.

The controller call :
 `Processing by AdminController#show as TURBO_STREAM`

The controller :

```
  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.turbo_stream do 
        Rails.logger.debug 'IN THE TURBO STREAM FORMAT'
      end
    end
  end
```

The view is in `show.turbo-stream.html.slim` (I tested without turbo-stream, same error)

error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat - AdminController#show is missing a template for this request format and variant.
request.formats: ["text/vnd.turbo-stream.html", "text/html"]
request.variant: []:
```

Comment: should be `show.turbo_stream.slim`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `show.turbo-stream.html.slim` triple extensions like so.

It is either `show.turbo-stream.html` or `show.turbo-stream.slim`
In your case both will work, but you need to modify your template according to the chosen extensions in order to be parsed, so either html or slim, not both.